# Trying to adapt this code for automatically sending emails from Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to adapt the code from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS3T2_qzJ8k
but I'm getting errors, can anyone spot the coding error? Thanks

I think there's confusion because in the video column E is referenced, I'm trying to reference column A - I'm not sure if some of the E letters in the original code are supposed to be changed or not

**ORIGINAL CODE FROM VIDEO**

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Approved") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][2];
  let d = new Date(rData[0][0]).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  let items = rData[0][3];
  let loc = rData[0][1];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  
  let msg = "Order number " + n + " (" + d + ") containing " + items + " items from " + loc + " Approved at " + now;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("receipient_email_address", "Approved Order", msg)
}
```

**MY MODIFIED CODE**

```
function sendMailEdit(a){
  if (a.range.columnStart != 1 || a.value >=2) return;
  const rData = a.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName('SUBSCRIPTIONS').getRange(a.range.rowStart,1,1,14).getValues();

  let mis = rData[0][1];
  let dat = new Date(rData[0][2]).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  let cos = rData[0][3];
  let aut = rData[0][4];
  let typ = rData[0][5];
  let des = rData[0][6];
  let pro = rData[0][7];
  let not = rData[0][8];
  let cnu = rData[0][9];
  let cna = rData[0][10];
  let sta = rData[0][13];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");

  let msg = "AUTOMATED EMAIL FROM :: NP PROJECTS SHEET 2021 :: " + sta + " " + dat + " " + mis + " | " + cna + " " + cnu + " | " + typ + " " + des + " " + pro + " " + not + " | " + cos + " " + aut + " | Change triggered at:" + now;
  
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("my_email@gmail.com",sta + " " + cna, msg)
}
```

Comment: keep the letters "e" in your code, they are not related to column E of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's a step in the right direction - I do still get an error tho:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnStart' of undefined
    at sendMailEdit(Code:2:15)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run the code from Script Editor by the button Run. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*When making an edit in a spreadsheet, you can benefit from the existence of an event object.*

In your case, `a` is the event object and it can return the following properties:

- `authMode`;
- `oldValue`;
- `range`;
- `source`
- `triggerUid`;
- `user`;
- `value`.

However, if you take a closer look at the `range` property, you can see that it returns an object of type [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) but the `columnStart` is not a method specific to the `Range` object.

If you want to retrieve the column at which the edit has been made, you should use the `getColumn` method.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script Range Class - getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn).

Comment: `columnStart` is a valid _property_ of the event object. You can get the number this way `var number = e.range.columnStart` (note, there are no brakets) I'm doing this constantly. It works fine.